# can not import csv file into Postgres, error invalid argument

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to copy csv file into postgres database table...
all the columns are according to the excel file ( number of columns are the same)
I'm using the command

```
    COPY bgl FROM '‪C:\Users\.....' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

it gives error

```
ERROR:  could not open file "‪C:\Users\..... for reading: Invalid argument
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Try `from 'c:/Users/...'`

Comment: does not work : (

Comment: Maybe the service account of postgresql (usually NETWORKSERVICE) can't acces the file. Try to copy it in some unprotected directory. The c:\Users\xxx directory is normally only accessible to the owning user.

Comment: Does the real command include the same invisible control characters that your post does?  Try taking those out.